# Where can I get (matching) sources for com.sun.jndi.ldap.* packages?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, sun

I am on JDK6_u26 and don't find `com.sun.jndi.ldap` package sources as part of sources.zip.
I believe they could be available from OpenJDK6 project, but I am not sure; and I am reading that the sources don't match the binaries in some cases.
Can someone shed some light as to how to get the sources (and if possible,exact matching the JDK binary build) for these packages for attaching them in the debugger?

A URL link/pointer would be great...
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), "Java SE 6 JDK Source Code" section. You have to sign the Community Licence in the process. NB This download contains *much*  more than the src.zip provided with the JDK.

Comment: This is the right location! Although one can't select source for a particular version of the binary build, the sources from here, seem to match! Thanks a lot, EJP!

Comment: well, this link does not contain the mentioned section anymore. So how to find it now?

Answer (score 1):

Since EJP's answer does not lead to a correct place any more, I give my answer here:

We can downlaod openJDK 8 [here](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk8/promoted/b132/openjdk-8-src-b132-03_mar_2014.zip), note that up to now the latest version is openJDK 8, in case that in the further we want to download the latest version, replace the number 8 in http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/ with the current version number, and go that link and we can find the source code download link.

Then we can find this package at `openJDK/src/openjdk/jdk/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/`.

For example, the connection pool is in `openJDK/src/openjdk/jdk/src/share/classes/com/sun/jndi/ldap/pool/Pool.java`