# how to find the exact sources of a JDK1.6 binary (including com.sun.jndi.*)

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to debug the classes com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration and com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.

As JDK binaries, I am using "Java for OSX 2012-003 Developer Package, Apr 19, 2012"
from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

This package contains the java.* and javax.* sources,
but it lacks some sources such as com.sun.jndi.*

so I downloaded the JDK sources of Nov 16, 2011 from here: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/
and I attached the sources to IntelliJ to debug.

However, the sources for com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration and com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx
do not correspond exactly between the binaries and the sources
(so IntelliJ shows points at incorrect lines when debugging step by step).

How to find the exact sources (including com.sun.jndi.*)
for "Java for OSX 2012-003 Developer Package, Apr 19, 2012"?

Or, how to find the binaries for the sources of Nov 16, 2011?
(it is not evident to compile the JDK sources)

Or, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760560/where-can-i-get-matching-sources-for-com-sun-jndi-ldap-packages

Comment: Do see the above link. I mistook it for native code.

Comment: the source code there http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html -> Java SE 6 JDK Source Code
points to openjdk-6-src-b24-14_nov_2011.tar.gz of November 16, 2011
that I was referring.
the binaries and the sources do not match (neither the mac binaries, nor the windows binaries)